# Transforming a string encoding a 3D array of booleans

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Suppose a 3D matrix is encoded in the form of a `string` as follows:

```
src = "1 0 0  1 1 1   0 0 0  0 0 1"
```

...where *three* spaces separate layers, *two* spaces separate rows, and *one* space separates columns.

Ultimately, my goal is to be able to transform it to a 3D matrix of `bool`:

```
console.log(result)  // [[[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]]
```

How can I transform `src` to obtain `result` using a purely functional approach? I am using `Lodash`.

Answer (score 3):

Why lodash? Use JS `map`

```
src.split("   ")
   .map(layer => layer.split("  ")
   .map(rows => rows.split(" ")
   .map(item => +item)));
// [ [ [ 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 1, 1 ] ], [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ] ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

My best bet is on a recursive function, but kudos in advance to the one who can do this in a *one-liner*. Given:

```
const src = "1 0 0  1 1 1   0 0 0  0 0 1"
```

Let's define `breakStuff/2` as:

```
function breakStuff(spaces, input) {
    if (spaces.length == 0) return parseInt(input) 
    return _.map(_.split(input, _.first(spaces)), i => breakStuff(_.tail(spaces), i))
}
```

Usage example:

```
breakStuff(['   ', '  ', ' '], src)
```

Which returns:

```
​​​​​​​​​​[ [ [ 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 1, 1 ] ], [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ] ] ]​​​​​
```

---

**Addenda**: according to your specification – although your own example uses `0`'s and `1`'s – the result should be composed of `bool`'s. For this, just change to the following line:

```
if (spaces.length == 0) return input == '1'
```

Which would return:

```
[ [ [ true, false, false ], [ true, true, true ] ],​​​​​
​​​​​  [ [ false, false, false ], [ false, false, true ] ] ]​​​​​
```